# Visual Studio Setup Project .vdproj Always Getting Modified

Tags: visual-studio-2010

Everytime I build my solution the setup project's .vdproj file always gets modified.

This has always annoyed me, but especially so at the moment since I am making some big changes and upgrading some projects and I am finding it very frustrating trying to figure out if the setup project actually has any changes which I should be concerned about.

Looking at the svn diff it just seems to modify guids and reorder sections for some reason. Is there anyway I can stop it doing this, or can someone explain why it feels the need to keep doing this when seemingly nothing has changed?

Thanks